# how to convert datetime from ISO Dates to "DD/MM/YYY hh:ss" format inside my javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime

I am working on a REST API, which return a field named modified in the following format:-

```
2018-02-23T00:25:12Z
```

While i want to show the modified in the following format:-

```
23/02/2018 00:25
```

now inside my javascript i tried converting the modified value to string and provide a format as follow:-

```
items[i].Modified.toString("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm");
```

but this did not change the date time format ??

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `toLocaleString`.

```js
var date = new Date('2018-02-23T00:25:12Z');
console.log(date.toLocaleString('es', {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: '2-digit',
  hour: '2-digit',
  minute: '2-digit',
  day: 'numeric',
  hour12: false
}))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

## Resource

- [`Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

Comment: but i want the date in the following format so the date should be `23/02/2018 00:25` instead of `02/23/2018 00:25`..

Comment: @johnG your format shows only numbers, so you can test any locale to format that date, i.e: `es`.  See the updated answer.

Comment: The format of *toLocaleString* is implementation dependent, even using the Intl object, you can't guarantee the format of the overall string, only the parts of it.

Comment: @RobG the documentation is clear, for example:  `US English uses month-day-year order` or `British English uses day-month-year order`, and so on.  That means that a specific locale can modify how the date object is formatted.

Comment: @Ele—by "the documentation" I guess you mean MDN. However, it's not normative, it's a public wiki of useful information. The specification (ECMA-402) doesn't define what format is used for which language, it passes that responsibility the [*Unicode Common Locale Data Repository*](http://cldr.unicode.org/core-spec#Locale), which also notes that user preferences deviate from "locale" preferences and that such preferences change over time. So just because a particular implementation formats a date for a certain language a particular way doesn't mean all implementations will do the same.

Comment: @RobG right right, I got it.  It makes sense. Have a good day!

Comment: @RobG now i tried this `var d = new Date(items[i].Modified.toString());
     d = d.toLocaleString('en-GB', {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: '2-digit',
  hour: '2-digit',
  minute: '2-digit',
  day: 'numeric',
  hour12: false
});` and looks like i got the format i want. something as follow `26 February 2018 02:07:42` .. so can i guarantee that this will always be the format ?

Comment: @johnG—in Safari I get a string like "23/02/2018, 10:25" so no, there is absolutely no guarantee at all, quite the opposite. You've specified `month: '2-digit'` but shown it as 'long'. If you want a specific format, do it manually or use a library, you can't rely on the Int object for exact formatting, it's not intended for that.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how you do?
But I hope my ways can help you

```
var today = new Date();
  var dd = today.getDate();
  var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

  var h = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();

  if (dd < 10) {
    dd = '0' + dd;
} 

if (mm < 10) {
  mm = '0' + mm;
} 

var today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy + ' ' + h + ':' + m;
```

---

**DEMO :**

```html
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
  var today = new Date();
  var dd = today.getDate();
  var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

  var h = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();

  if (dd < 10) {
    dd = '0' + dd;
} 

if (mm < 10) {
  mm = '0' + mm;
} 

var today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy + ' ' + h + ':' + m;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = today;
</script>
```